# How to add multiple markers to map in Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-api-geocoding

I have an array of address data, and I would like to know, how would I add multiple markers to my Mapbox map? I am pretty sure I would somehow have to loop through my array, but I am not sure how would I add it to my map, if it is at all possible. Here is my code:

```
var streetArray = JSON.stringify(<%- streets %>);
var cityArray = JSON.stringify(<%- cities %>);
var countryArray = JSON.stringify(<%- countries %>);
var zipArray = JSON.stringify(<%-zips %>);

var streetValue = JSON.parse(streetArray);
var cityValue = JSON.parse(cityArray);
var countryArray = JSON.parse(countryArray);
var zipValue = JSON.parse(zipArray);

mapboxgl.accessToken = //my_access_token
const mapboxClient = mapboxSdk({ accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken });
mapboxClient.geocoding
    .forwardGeocode({
    query: streetValue[6].value + " " + cityValue[6].value + " AZ " + zipValue[6].value,
    autocomplete: false,
    limit: 1
    })
    .send()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(streetValue[6].value + " " + cityValue[6].value + " AZ " + zipValue[6].value);
        if (
        !response ||
        !response.body ||
        !response.body.features ||
        !response.body.features.length
        ) {
            console.error('Invalid response:');
        console.error(response);
        return;
    }
    const feature = response.body.features[0];

    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
        center: feature.center,
        zoom: 10
    });


// Create a marker and add it to the map.
new mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(feature.center).addTo(map);
});
```

I understand that `setLngLat` adds the marker to the map, but I think I need to make multiple calls to the API in order to add more than one. How would I do this with my code?

Comment: addTo adds a marker to the map. https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-a-marker/ might give you a hint